# Concatenating a map char and integer value to create a new string

Tags: c++

I want to create a string `s` from the elements of a map `m`, which has `<char, int>` datatypes for its elements. For example - let the `element = ('1', 2)`, so the string should be `"12"`.

I tried to convert the second value into a `char` before adding it to the string by various methods, but it doesn't work.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    unordered_map<char, int> m;
    m.insert({'1',1});
    m.insert({'2',1});
    string s = "";
    for(auto value: m){
        s+=value.first;
        char v = value.second; 
        s+=v;
    }
    cout<<s<<endl;
}
```

Output:

> 2☺1☺

Comment: you have to + '0' to get the ascii value of the digit

Comment: Thanks, it works, what should I search to get more info about this

Comment: Integer `1` is not the same value as ASCII character `'1'` (integer 49). That is why you have to add `'0'` (integer 48) to `1` to get `'1'`

Comment: you can also use [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) for c++11 and later: `s+=value.first + to_string(value.second);`

Comment: Note: structured bindings in C++17 (and later) for-loops might clean this up a bit.  `for (auto &[ch, i] : m) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to convert your `int` to a string such that it can be concatenated to another string. For demonstration purposes we can eliminate the `std::unordered_map` as it is not relevant to the issue.

You do want to talk about converting it to a string rather than a `char` as there is no way to guarantee it'll be between 0 and 9, and converting a larger integer to a character will yield results you're probably not looking for.

As noted in comments, one to to use [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

```
int i = 42;
std::string s = "hello";
std::string s2 = s + " " + std::to_string(i);
```

Another approach would be to build your string with a [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int i = 42;
    std::string s = "hello";
    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << s << " " << i;

    std::string s2 = ss.str();

    std::cout << s2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
hello 42
```